# What is (full) semantic transparency?

Tags: architecture, http, protocol

I was reading the RFC 2616 regarding HTTP/1.1 when this term came up:

> Therefore, the HTTP/1.1 protocol provides these important elements: [...] Protocol features that provide **full semantic transparency** when this is required by all parties.

[...]

> The Cache-Control header allows a client or server to transmit a
>      variety of directives in either requests or responses. These
>      directives typically override the default caching algorithms. As a
>      general rule, if there is any apparent conflict between header
>      values, the most restrictive interpretation is applied (that is, the
>      one that is most likely to preserve **semantic transparency**).

My questions are:

- What is semantic transparency? What makes it full?
- What's advantageous about having a protocol which is semantically transparent?
- How can I tell a protocol has this property?

Comment: [RFC 2616 is dead](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead). In terms of the meaning of semantic transparency, have you read e.g. http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/dder/cm214old/cm214-http4.ppt?

Comment: Thanks for the links! So to sum up, full semantic transparency refers to a protocol which may involve one or more intermediaries which will not alter the request in any way?

Answer (score 3):

> A cache behaves in a “semantically transparent” manner, with respect
>   to a particular response, when its use affects neither the requesting
>   client nor the origin server, except to improve performance. When a
>   cache is semantically transparent, the client receives exactly the
>   same response that it would have received had its request been handled
>   directly by the origin server.

Source: https://www.w3.org/Talks/9608HTTP/tsld014.htm